# C# Problems with simple list display

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, ienumerable

I am making an animal shelter application, in which I have to create either a cat or a dog, and by creating it and adding it to a list. I have a button that is supposed to show all the animals of the list, and another button supposed to show all the dogs. When I click one those two buttons, only the last created animal appears. Can you give me some guidance?

```
    namespace AnimalShelter
    {
    class AnimalShelter
    {
    private string Name;
    private int TelNumber;
    private List<Animal> AnimalList;

    public AnimalShelter(string name, int telnumber)
    {
        this.AnimalList = new List<Animal>();
        this.Name = name;
        this.TelNumber = telnumber;
    }

    public Animal FindAnimal(string id)
    {
        foreach (Animal anim in this.AnimalList)
        {
            if (id == anim.ChipRegistrationNumber)
            {
                return anim;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    public bool RemoveAnimal(string id)
    {
        if (id.Length <= 0)
            return false;
        Animal ao = this.FindAnimal(id);
        if (ao == null)
            return false;
        this.AnimalList.Remove(ao);
        return true;
    }

    public bool AddNewAnimal(Animal ao)
    {
        if (ao == null)
            return false;

        if (this.FindAnimal(ao.ChipRegistrationNumber) != null)
            return false;

        this.AnimalList.Add(ao);

        return true;
    }




    public List<Dog> GetAllDogs()
    {
       List<Dog> temp = new List<Dog>();
       foreach (Animal animal in this.AnimalList)
       {
           if (animal.GetType() == typeof(Dog))
               temp.Add((Dog)animal);

       }
       return temp;
    }

    public List<Cat> GetAllCats()
    {
        List<Cat> temp = new List<Cat>();
        foreach (Animal animal in this.AnimalList)
        {
            if (animal.GetType() == typeof(Cat))
                temp.Add((Cat)animal);
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public List<Animal> GetAllAnimals()
    {
        return AnimalList;
    }

    }
}
```

And this is the actual form, in which I create the cat or dog, and have the buttons to show all animals, or to show all dogs!

```
   private void AnimalCreation_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = tbname.Text;
        string number = tbregno.Text;
        DateTime date = this.DateBroughtIn.Value.Date;
        DateTime lastwalked = this.LastWalked.Value.Date;
        string badhabits = tbbadhabbits.Text;

        if (name.Length <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A Name Must Be Given");
        }

        if (number.Length <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" A number must be given ");
        }

        if (date > DateTime.Now)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid date, can not be added");
        }
        else
        {
            Animal a = null;
            if (dog.Checked)
            {

                a = new Dog(number, date, name, lastwalked);
                this.MyAnimalShelter.AddNewAnimal(a);
                MessageBox.Show("Dog Successfully added");
            }
            if (cat.Checked)
            {
                if (badhabits.Length <= 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Bad Habbits must be filled");
                }
                else
                {
                    a = new Cat(number, date, name, badhabits);
                    this.MyAnimalShelter.AddNewAnimal(a);
                    MessageBox.Show("Cat Successfully added");
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private void AllAnimalsShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Animal animal in MyAnimalShelter.GetAllAnimals())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.Add(animal);
        }
    }

    private void AllDogsShow_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Animal animal in MyAnimalShelter.GetAllDogs())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.Add(animal);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seriously, instead of looping through your list trying to find entities, you should use lambda expressions using the provided methods, e.g.: `this.AnimalList.Where(k => k.ChipRegistrationNumber == id).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: I am in first year Computer science and we haven`t yet gotten to these kinds of things. I`m using most basic stuff, that I have learned up until now :)

Comment: Check a string with `String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)` instead of `s.Length<=0`. This eliminates at least the risk of NullReferenceExceptions.

Answer (score 4):

You clear the list every iteration of the `foreach` so for every animal in the datastructure you clear the list and add one animal. that's why you end up with only the last animal in the list.

You need to do like this:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
foreach (Animal animal in MyAnimalShelter.GetAllAnimals())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(animal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You clear the list inside the `foreach` loop in `AllAnimalsShow_Click()` and `AllDogsShow_Click_1()`.

It should be cleared *before* the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your `AllDogsShow_click_1()` you call `listBox1.Items.Clear()` *inside* the `foreach` block.

Move that to before the `foreach` and see what happens. Same with the `AllAnimalsShow_Click()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you clear your list in the foreach loop , for each animal!
You'll have to Clear it before entering the loop!

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
foreach (Animal animal in MyAnimalShelter.GetAllAnimals())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(animal);
}
```